# $\sum_{n \in \mathbb Z} |\hat {f}(n)|^p |n|^{p-2}) \leq C_p \|f\|^p_L$ where $p \in (1,2],$ $f \in L^p(\Bbb T)$

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-series, function-spaces

I'm trying to prove that for p $\in$ (1,2] and for some $C_p$ > 0,  
 $$\sum_{n \in \mathbb Z} |\hat {f}(n)|^p |n|^{p-2} \leq C_p \|f\|^p_{L^p} \text{ for all } f \in L^p(\Bbb T)$$

Now we first note that if we take p $\in$ (1,2]

Then $|n|^{p-2} = \frac{1}{|n|^{2-p}} \leq 1$

Thus, $\sum_{n \in \mathbb Z} |\hat {f}(n)|^p |n|^{p-2} \leq \sum_{n \in \mathbb Z} |\hat {f}(n)|^p$ for  all  $f \in L^p(\Bbb T)$

For $p = 2$,

> we know that $\|f\|^2_{L^2(\Bbb T)} = \sum_{n\in \Bbb Z} |\hat f(n)|^2$ for all $f \in L^2(\Bbb T)$ 
>  So  $\sum_{n \in \mathbb Z} |\hat {f}(n)|^p |n|^{p-2} \leq C_p \|f\|^p_{L^{p}}$ for  $p = 2$.

For $p = 1$

> $\sum_{n \in \mathbb Z} |\hat {f}(n)|^p |n|^{p-2}$ with p = 1 is $\sum_{n \in \mathbb Z} \frac{|\hat {f}(n)^p|}{|n|}$ and according to this example [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3730297/sum-n-in-mathbb-z-frac-hat-fnn-infty-for-all-f-in-l1-bb/3730332#3730332)  , there exists such examples where $\sum_{n \in \mathbb Z}  |\hat{f}(n)|^p |n|^{p-2}= \infty$ for $p = 1$.

**So how do I prove the cases for  $p\in (1,2)$?**

Comment: This smells of the Marcinkiewicz interpolation theorem.

Comment: @OliverDiaz Could you explain more why the operator works? I suppose we're looking for some operator $T$ such that $\|Tf\|^p_p = \sum_{n \in \mathbb{Z}} \hat{f}(n)^p |n|^{2-p}$...

Comment: @Abhigyan Saha: I think there is a problem with the power $(\hat{f}(n))^p$ for $\hat{f}(n)$ is complex in general so the inequality does not make sense there. Did you mean $|\hat{f}(n)|^p$ instead?

Comment: @OliverDiaz Ah yes! You're right. I've edited it accordingly

Comment: @PhoemueX Can you smell weak (1,1) ?

Comment: @AbhigyanSaha Can you kindly tell the source of the question?